# Visual Studio XML comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is an example, don't bother to read it just notice how big things can get:

```
/// <summary>
/// An animated sprite is stored as one image, visually divided in
/// matrix-like form where each frame is one element. Frames are numbered
/// from 0 to some number n. The top left frame in the matrix is at (0, 0)
/// and the bottom right is at (n, n). Given a frame number this method
/// returns a position in that matrix.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="frame">Frame number.</param>
/// <returns>Matrix position.</returns>
/// <remarks></remarks>
/// <seealso cref="Book: C# Game Programming for Serious Game Creation."/>
public System.Drawing.Point GetMatrixPositionFromFrameNumber(int frame)
{
    System.Drawing.Point point = new System.Drawing.Point();
    point.Y = frame / framesX;
    point.X = frame - (point.Y * framesX);
    return point;            
}
```

Do you guys comment like this or do you somehow get comments out of your source files?

Thank you

Comment: isnt this suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com.. its nt a question persay

Comment: Do you guys comment even one line methods?

Comment: I'm quite anal when it comes to commenting, so I comment everything except fields. Public API it is quite important, but for private methods, its useful for when other people are maintaining the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ancient chinese proverb that says : "The closer the comment is to the code, the better it is.".

I'm not surprised by the length.

You can later extract this information from source code with tools like sancastle, or else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the numbers of lines within a method should have any bearing on the size of the XML comments.

Generally the XML comments are for public members, so the consumer of that code has no idea what the inner workings are, so they won't care if the method is 1 line or 100 lines long. They document things like the behavior and usage, again, nothing to do with the amount of code behind the scenes.

Sometimes it can be hard to determine how much information to give though, your example seems overly long and there are often ways to reduce the amount of information that needs to be given in the comment. More descriptive method names, providing overloads for methods, more classes with fewer responsibilities etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite consistent when it comes to commenting. Generally I will do:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates an instance of <see cref="ITemplate"/> from the specified string template.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The model type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="razorTemplate">The string template.</param>
/// <param name="model">The model instance.</param>
/// <returns>An instance of <see cref="ITemplate"/>.</returns>
ITemplate CreateTemplate<T>(string razorTemplate, T model);
```

Whereby `<summary>` represents a summary of what the operation does. In instances where I need to provide more clarity, or to explain an expected behaviour, I use `<remarks>`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tests that an isolated template service cannot use the same application domain as the 
/// main application domain.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// An isolated template service will unload it's child application domain on Dispose. We need to ensure
/// it doesn't attempt to unload the current application domain that it is running in. This may or may
/// not be the main application domain (but is very likely to be).
/// </remarks>
[Test]
public void IsolatedTemplateService_WillThrowException_WhenUsingMainAppDomain()
{
    Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() =>
    {
        using (var service = new IsolatedTemplateService(() => AppDomain.CurrentDomain))
        { }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ghost Doc or the Visual Studio summaries and if those get too big I collapse them. I tend to be more concise about what I put in there though, expecting readers to infer some of the meaning of the method from the method name and possibly other comments or code.